# WEP shared-key authentication response generation

Tags: authentication, wep

While I was capturing packets with Wireshark using my phone I tried connect to my access point which has WEP shared-key authentication (only for testing purposes) and I got the authentication packets which contained the IV, challenge text, etc. Then I tired to represent the ciphertext what my phone sent. So I already know the password and I took the IV, after that concatenated these two and put in the RC4 algorithm what gave me a keystream. I  xored the keystream and the challenge text but this always gives me different chipertext than my phone sent.

Maybe I concatenate the IV and password in the wrong way or I'm using wrong algorithm and why is the response in the provided image is 147 bytes long?

[Image of wireshark captured packets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqjJ4.png)

#### Code what I'm using

```
def KSA(key):
    keylength = len(key)
    S = range(256)
    j = 0
    for i in range(256):
        j = (j + S[i] + key[i % keylength]) % 256
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]  # swap
    return S

def PRGA(S):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while True:
        i = (i + 1) % 256
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256
        S[i], S[j] = S[j], S[i]  # swap
        K = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256]
        yield K

def RC4(key):
    S = KSA(key)
    return PRGA(S)
```